# QGIS Advanced String Filter Expression returns too many results

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, filter

`"GNR"` is a string column and I expect the filter expression `"GNR"='.11'` to only return the feature with the value `'0.11'`.

Why are the other features with values of `'.110'`and `'.1100'` included?

Is there something wrong with my query?

[image: string filter expression returns too many results]

Comment: What if the column GNR was column of strings and that we only wanted to filter the strings that contained a certain sequence of characters? For example the string "(historical)" that ends certain strings in the list. So there is no perfect equal.

Comment: Easy: "NAME"LIKE'%(historical)%'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your query.

**`=`** is a comparison operator and it returns all the records which begins with your string

Use this instead:

```
"GNR" LIKE '.11'
```

When you compare alphabetic characters, use `ILIKE` instead.

---

**EDIT**

In `QGIS 2.0.1` or newer you can use regular expressions, also:

```
regexp_match("GNR", '^.11$')
```

where:

- **`^`** indicates the start of the string;
- **`$`** indicates the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. For me, coming from an SQL background, 'LIKE' and '=' act just the other way round.

Comment: This is a bug then. `=` should be doing an exact match.

Comment: Ok.  This bug/implementation detail.  QgsExpression will try and convert both sides to a double and compare that for faster results.

Comment: You can also do this: `"GNR" ~ '^.11$'` which is a regex match and will force a string.

Comment: Nathan did great observations! Therefore, due to the perfect compatibility with the older QGIS versions (tested on 1.8 and 1.7), "GNR" ~ '^.11$' is the way to go when you need equality!